# FS writeFile(Sync) causing ws.broadcast to not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, fs

I was trying to learn the `WebSocket` API by writing a simple chat application in NodeJS. I needed to save the messages in a file called `messages.json` that would look something like this:

```json
[
  [
    "username",
    "message"
  ],
  [
    "username",
    "message"
  ],
  ...
]
```

I had already completed the client part of it. The HTML and Javascript files looked like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stuff</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="chatText" placeholder="Message" />
    <button
      id="sendBtn"
      onclick='if (document.getElementById("chatText").value.trim() !== "") ws.send(document.getElementById("chatText").value + " " + user); document.getElementById("chatText").value = ""'
    >
      <span style="margin-left: 5px"></span>Send<span
        style="margin-left: 5px"
      ></span>
    </button>
    <br />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
var user = prompt('Username?').trim()

while (user.split(' ').length > 1 || user.trim() === '') {
  user = prompt('Username?').trim()
}

var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

ws.onopen = function (event) {
  console.log('Connection successfully opened!');
};

ws.onerror = function (err) {
  console.log('err: ', err);
}

ws.onmessage = function (event) {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.classList.add('chatMsg')
  div.innerText = event.data.split(/ (?=[^ ]+$)/)[1] + ': ' + event.data.split(/ (?=[^ ]+$)/)[0]
  document.body.appendChild(div)
};
```

I used a regex to split the data at the last space character, because I found out that I couldn't send an array or an object from the client to the server or vice versa, and the username couldn't contain any spaces, although I might have been overcomplicating things accidentally.

Then, the server-side NodeJS code had to be written. I completed it as far as this when I wanted to save the messages permanently:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('public/index.html');
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('server started'));

const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', ((ws) => {
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    wss.broadcast(message);
  });

  ws.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Connection ended...');
  });
}));

wss.broadcast = function broadcast(msg) {
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    client.send(msg);
  });
};
```

So far, I was able to send messages from one browser tab, and the other tab was able to receive them correctly and send another message, and so on. I thought that the best way to save the messages permanently would be a JSON file, so I created  a file named `messages.json`, which was mentioned above.

At the start of the program, I read the file by including `var messages = require('./messages.json')` and `require`d the module `fs` to write to `messages.json`.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const messages = require('./messages.json');
```

I then changed `ws.on('message', (message) => { ...` to look like the following:

```js
ws.on('message', (message) => {
  messages.push(message.split(/ (?=[^ ]+$)/))
  fs.writeFile('./messages.json', JSON.stringify(messages), () => { })
  wss.broadcast(message);
});
```

Then, I opened two tabs in my browser at `file:// ... /public/index.html`. I sent a message from the first tab. I then switched to the second tab and tried to send a message. I typed something into the input and pressed the "Send" button, and the text inside the input disappeared like it was supposed to, but nothing else happened. I then switched back to the first tab and tried the same thing, but it behaved the same way as the second tab did. I switched back to the VSCode window and checked the terminal, but there were no errors. I opened `messages.json` and saw only one message inside the array. The file looked like this:

```json
[
  [
    "user",
    "test"
  ]
]
```

I was confused, because I had sent three messages, but only one had been recorded inside the file. I reset `messages.json` to `[]` and used `fs.readFileSync` instead of `fs.readFile`. Nothing changed, Then, for debugging purposes, I changed the line `fs.writeFile('./messages.json', JSON.stringify(messages), () => { })` to `console.log('test')`. I closed both the tabs and opened them again. Then, I sent a message from the first tab, one from the second, and another one from the first tab. Everything worked like it was supposed to, and both tabs showed the messages. The terminal showed the output:

```
test
test
test
```

It was working as expected. Why is it not working with `fs.readFile` and `fs.readFileSync`?

To run and reload the server, I am using an NPM script named `live` with `nodemon`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "live": "nodemon index.js"
},
```

To start the server, I just simply ran `nodemon index.js` in the terminal.

My directory structure:

```
node_modules
public
  |-- index.html
  |-- script.js
index.js
messages.json
package.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `require()` to read the JSON file, because it was the shorter and easier way to do it. I was able to fix it by using `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./messages.json', () => { }).toString())` instead of `require('./messages.json')`.

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()

var messages = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./messages.json', () => { }).toString())

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('public/index.html')
})

app.listen(8000, () => { })

const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 })

wss.on('connection', ((ws) => {
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    messages.push(message.split(/ (?=[^ ]+$)/))
    fs.writeFile('./messages.json', JSON.stringify(messages), () => { })
    wss.broadcast(message)
  })

  messages.forEach((item) => {
    ws.send(item.join(' '))
  })

  ws.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Connection ended...')
  })
}))

wss.broadcast = function broadcast(msg) {
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    client.send(msg)
  })
}
```

**Edit:**

As @Bergi has told me in the comments, it was because of `nodemon` - it was watching the file as a dependency (yet another downfall of lazily using `require()` to read JSON files) and restarting the server every time `messages.json` was edited, and that's why it didn't work after the first chat message. I was able to confirm this by running my app using just `node` instead of `nodemon`.

Comment: The question originally didn't make any sense to me, but now that you mention it: `nodemon` must have watched the `messages.json` file that was required as a dependency, and restarted your server every time you wrote a new message.

Comment: @Bergi Oh! I didn't realize that could happen. I will test my app without `nodemon`, and if there is a different result, edit my answer right away.

Comment: I'd also expect restart to be apparent from the logs…

Comment: @Bergi Yes. Unfortunately, I don't pay much attention to those. Anyway, it works without `nodemon` and just using `node`. I will edit my answer.